# nginx proxy_pass with rewrite in url not keeping the original paths

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to setup nginx to forward incoming requests in the following way:

```
http://localhost/service -> http://localhost:8080
http://localhost/service/foo -> http://localhost:8080/foo
```

Now I am able to achieve the first line with the following config:

```
...

upstream service {
    server service:8080;
}

... 

location /service/ {
    server_name_in_redirect off;
    proxy_pass         http://service;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 }
```

but when I add extra paths (e.g. /foo) the url is rewritten in this way

```
http://localhost/foo/
```

therefore I will never be able to reach localhost:8080/foo. Any ideas on how to make this work?
Thanks in advance

Comment: How is your `service` upstream defined? Why do not simply use `http://service/;` for this `location` block without any additional rewrites?

Comment: @IvanShatsky I edited the question to include the upstream. I tried to remove the rewrite (I had tried it before but it would fail, adding the last / made it work), but I'm facing the same issue